# How to identify which request from Jmeter was slowest?

Tags: jmeter

We are running performance tests using JMeter. In the Aggregate report we are able to view the minimum and maximum times. We now want to identify exactly which request from JMeter took the maximum time that was reported, so that we can perform a root cause analysis. So, how do we identify that request in JMeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
   ```

   it will generate CSV file containing all samplers statistics so if you sort by `elapsed` column in the `timeStamp` column using [MS Excel or equivalent](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx) you will see the Unix timestamp so you can figure out the exact time when the "longest" request was fired:

   [image]
2. Another option is adding a unique identifier like number of current thread, number of iteration, URL, whatever

   [image]

   it can be done using [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or [Pre-Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars)